# Showing Pie charts in QGIS Legends

Tags: qgis, legend, chart

I would like to display some pie charts on my map. They show in the map frame perfectly but in legend on the print composer I am unable to show the legend for the pie charts. QGIS just shows the style of the point underneath the pie.

Is it possible to get these shown?

Using QGIS v1.8 from OSGEO4W on Windows XP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not yet possible as far as I know. You can help yourself by creating legend images using an image processing program.

Answer (score 7):

Someone has written a small external application which creates legends for pie-charts, the format of the legend is SVG. It looks excellent, have a look here:

http://www.qgis.nl/2012/05/02/staafdiagrammen/?lang=en

Comment: The bar charts look good.  I did not find anything about pie charts though.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I ran into the same problem, but I found a creative solution. To be fair without using using outside program, it only works with 4 data in the chart, but I believe it can be any amount.

- Within composer you draw a circle, then go to properties.
- Change the Style to Simple marker.
- There are pre-drawn shapes, like segments of a circle.
- Choose the one you need, rotate it, give the same size/color, as on the map.
- And you are done!

[image]

[image]